# Unable to login into Hyperledger Cello operator dashboard

Tags: hyperledger-cello

I have installed Hyperledger Cello following the instructions [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/blob/master/docs/setup_master.md) The operator dashboard opens up at port 8080 but when I try logging in with the credentials admin:pass as suggested like these to auth realms url and i get error site cannot be reached as show below

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8083/auth/realms/cello-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=cello-operator-dashboard&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxx.xx.xx.xx:%3A8080%2Foidc_callback&scope=openid+email&access_type=offline&response_type=code&state=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjogInAxenFid1VMQnI0U2N4T05QYVNqc1luejhmMHMxN3diIiwgImRlc3RpbmF0aW9uIjogImV5SmhiR2NpT2lKSVV6STFOaUo5LkltaDBkSEE2THk4MUxqa3VNamt1TdfdNd09qZ3dPREF2SWcuTnItSmhpN3lXR1puTE1VdEx0Qmc1TUpRZ1N0SlFMeFF3YklLRHI3UDd2VSJ9&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fxx.xx.xx.xx:%3A8080%2Foidc_callback

i have given following env variables.

Are there any other configuration i need to do for realms to log into the operator dashboard? I can't log into the operator dashboard and I can't access the user dashboard. The user dashboard container is running as shown below but unable to access dashboard Please help.

[Docker running container Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spRXj.png)

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I have started the cello services with below commands

cd cello
sudo make reset 
SERVER_PUBLIC_IP=xx.xx.xx.xx make start

and in browser use this URL: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/

Note:  Replace xx.xx.xx.xx with your public IP.

Comment: I need to set the Makefile, only environment variable is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, with Cello 0.9.0 @GaurangSing's answer didn't work. In the end, what helped me was to edit `Makefile` in the cello root folder, and change line : `SERVER_PUBLIC_IP ?= 127.0.0.1` with the IP of my own server.